# Integration of Spring Cloud Gateway With Spring Cloud Sleuth

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-sleuth

I could not find any example which is integrating Spring cloud Sleuth with the Spring Cloud Gateway. Want a Sample Project doing the Integration successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use your favorite search engine and type in `spring cloud sleuth gateway sample` most likely one of the first results will be this https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-sleuth-samples/tree/main/gateway

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcin for the Quick Response . Somehow, It did not pop up in my search results